# Could not find Kotlin classes in feature module from another module

Tags: android, kotlin, android-source, android-studio-3.0

Could not find Kotlin classes in a module with `com.android.feature` plugin from another feature module. For example, in Android Instant Apps, Kotlin classes in "base" feature can't be referenced from any feature module.

- Gradle Version: 4.0-20170417000025+0000-all
- Android Plugin Version: 3.0.0-alpha3
- Module Compile Sdk Version: 25
- Module Build Tools Version: 26.0.0
- Android SDK Tools Version: 26.0.2
- Kotlin Version: 1.1.2-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62653553), it has been fixed with Android SDK Built-Tools to 27.0.2

Please update your Android SDK Built-Tools to 27.0.2 And ensure you are on Android Studio 3.0.1 or newer.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62653553) they will re-open to examine. Thanks!